# Intermittent ASP.net IIS8.5 uncatchable 500 internal-server-error on Azure cloud service

Tags: asp.net, azure, error-handling, internal-server-error

Lets start with a little background information. I am running a very simple ASP.net MVC Azure cloud service (a web role, Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5). This service receives statistics from a flash client, which posts data roughly every 10 seconds (for potentially very large number of clients) and JavaScript. All the service contains is a single controller with two simple actions with a bunch of parameters (representing the individual statistics which are send in various combinations). All the service does is set the CORS and cookie responses (the clients/JavaScript can be embedded on random domains), verify the integrity of the received data and then store it into an Azure table storage account.

In order to ensure our service operates optimally we use New Relic to track service performance, and in order to ensure that our data is accurate (i.e. we successfully record all received messages) we implemented a custom error handling solution so we can fix any problems/bugs that might arise.

We have load tested our service using jmeter and encountered no problems, but now that we have deployed to a live environment and our service is being used we are starting to encounter occasional 500 internal server errors (approx 5% of requests). The big problem being that our own error handling code is not detecting these errors, however New Relic does report certain requests generating a 500 internal server error (with no further information like a stack trace, sometimes with, sometimes without reported parameters).

Our custom error handling consists of an HTTP module which registers to both the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and the context.Error events. In theory this should be catching (and then logging) any exceptions which are not already being caught (and logged) inside our own code. Relevant web.config sections are configured in the following manner:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

and

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
<modules>
  <add type="namespace.UnhandledExceptionModule" name="UnhandledExceptionModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

However, this is not the case. I have tried turning on all kinds of logging but the IIS logs are useless (they only show that a 500 response was returned, but no other useful information). The only useful information I have been able to gather is from the failed request traces, but I have not been able to determine what the actual problem is from that information (googling the error code or exception leads to nothing concrete). A screenshot of the relevant section of a failed trace can be found here:

http://i57.tinypic.com/20acrip.jpg

I also uploaded the complete trace here:

http://pastebin.com/fDt3thvr

Each failed request generates exactly the same log, so the errors we are seeing are consistently being caused by the same problem. However, I am not able to determine what this problem is, let alone find a way of fixing it. Even though I have an error code and message, googling them only returns very old topics on issues that have been fixed 6 years ago.

It is pretty important for our business that these messages can be recorded with a high degree of accuracy, but as it stands now I have no further ideas on how to gain better information on what is happening on these servers. We are also not able to replicate this behavior in a controlled environment.

Also, our error logging itself does work properly. 'Normal' errors are logged as expected and we have also verified the HTTP module actually works.

Edit:

The controller pseudo code is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method(...)
{
    // Set cookie and CORS reponse, check for early out.
    if(earlyOut)
         return 404;

    // Store received values.
    azuretable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(...));

    return 200;
}
```

Edit2:

I have spend some time analyzing failed request traces and they mostly seem to be generated by users with IE9. I actually managed to reproduce the error 2 times by quickly leaving the page while it is loading, as the problem seems to be caused by aborted Ajax calls (which we make the most of during page load). Why would an aborted call cause a 500 error though instead of being handled neatly?

Comment: What is the instance size? 500 might be caused by CPU spikes and/or memory spikes.

Comment: The instance size is small, but according to the server management tools we are at around 1-2% cpu use and memory use does not exceed 70%, basically the load on the server is negligible, but we have seen issue's before with the number of connections being made to a database, but that is why we switched to table storage.

Comment: Table storage has it's own scalebility limits, make sure you're not hitting those. To find out, enable Diagnostics on Storage and then when the issue occurs, check the logs. Also, keep in mind that the small instance has a smaller network throughput (not sure how big your request, but just in case). Lastly, what I would check is thread starvation in case you're using the TPL library (Tasks). Unfortunately, it's quite a vague problem so I can't provide more definite answer as this point.

Comment: According to the Azure management portal we are not hitting any limits. We did enable the diagnostics at one point which helped us resolve another (unrelated) issue but it showed no other errors. Our max throughput is 600 RPM with a I/O of ~90kb/s out and ~70kb/s in. We are asynchronously sending the data to the table storage (and not awaiting the result), but even when we did this synchronously the problem occurred. We had problems before switching to ASP/table storage with connection counts and TCP pool starvation, perhaps something similar is happening here, but the numbers are so low.

Comment: Those might be two unrelated problems but because they look similar, they cause confusion. Can you share the piece of code that does the async call and you don't want and also what is the method signature? E.g. public Task<bool> MyCall(). I suspect that you might be return void from the async task, which causes a whole lot of issues. I still thing that might be thread starvation. You could also enable a Performance Counter and see how .NET is in terms of Threads at that point.

Comment: @PanagiotisKefalidis I edited my original question with the controller psuedo code. I think you may have misunderstood me, none of our own code is async, we use the azure storage library to store the data. We use the async version as we are not interested in the result (could this cause thread pool issues?). We did try using the sync version of the Execute method, but the problem still occurred, which made me think using the async version was not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Do the cookies exceed 4k ? The same thing happened to us on IIS, and the requests sometimes ended up with 500 Internal Server error. The errors were virtually untraceable.
I reproduced the issue by simply inflating a cookie over the 4093 bytes limit.

Comment: We only use a few very small cookies, around ~100 bytes total.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is because you are not awaiting your async method call, or your are not returning an awaitable response. I had exactly this issue when I forgot to do that.

```
await azuretable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(...))
```

Then you should be good. I think you'll find that the async call is finishing after your call has completed back to the caller.